big query data transformation logic
I am trying to get a data in a specified format, currently this is in the form.

I want to write a sql query which would get me the data in this form

I tried with converting it to array and unnest but not getting the desired result, any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!
I tried with converting it to array and unnest but not getting the desired result, any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

First we need the schema of the table, but it looks like x, y and z are the array, so I'll write a quick query for that. Still, it's better if you can provide the schema. Also, do x, y and z always have 2 items or it's also not fixed?

Thanks a lot, but its just a sample. I do get the data as required but how can i get it in the same format since these are hierarchies and 1, 10 are like sub categories to categories 3,9...Its like- under 3(category), i have 1 and 10 sub-categories and under 9(category) we have 1 and 10 as sub-categories...so the ordering matters here. Is there a way to achieve the same order

You should provide example data to make it understandable for us.

As I asked in the comment, it would be better if you can provide more details about the data.
However, here, I created a reproducible version of your data in raw_data, and then I unnested x2 to bring the first part of the query. Here, I had to deduplicate so I used a distinct statement.
In the second part, you want to match y and z by their indexes, so I used a where statement in the bottom.
I hope it solves the problem.
with
raw_data as
(
  select 
    3 as event_id, 
    [56238.11, 56238.11] as x,
    [1, 10] as y,
    [41171.62, 102813.99] as z
  union all
  select 
    9 as event_id,
    [1098.13, 1098.13] as x,
    [1, 10] as y,
    [612.72, 1135.72] as z
)
select distinct
  event_id,
  x2
from raw_data
join unnest(x) as x2

union all

select
  y2,
  z2
from raw_data
join unnest(y) as y2 with offset y_i
join unnest(z) as z2 with offset z_i
where y_i = z_i

